# Extracting individual strings of an object returned by selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website using selenium in python where I am finding all that elements that belong to a particular classes 'left' and 'right'.

Selenium returns an object which when printed iteratively prints a series of text.

```
left = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='left')
right = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='right')
```

When printing this iteratively, I get the following:

```
for elem in left:
    print(left.text)

a
b
c

a
b
c
d


a
c
d
```

And similar set of values for the right object.

I want to create a dictionary with the values from the left as keys and values of right as values in the dictionary (appended as a list to each correspnding unique key.) How could one do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the program to overwrite the key values then use this it will create a list if there are more than one value for the same key.

Try this.

```
dict_ = {}
for k, v in zip(left, right):
    if k in dict_:
        if isinstance(dict_[k], list):
            dict_[k].append(v)
        else:
            dict_[k] = [dict_[k], v]
    else:
        dict_[k] = v


print(dict_)
```

Else

Try this.

```
dict_ = { k : v for k, v in zip(left, right)}
print(dict_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty `dictionary` and then use python `zip()` function to iterate left and right list.

```
left = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='left')
right = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='right')
result={}
for eleL,eleR in zip(left, right):
   result[eleL.text]=eleR.text
   
print(result)
```

Comment: What if there are two same keys?

Comment: @codester_09, If the same keys then value will be overwrite. Lets say key1 hold `x` if Key1 gets `y` it will overwrite with `y`.